# htaccess redirect index.php to file, only if there are parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm tring to implement a htaccess redirect that occour only if there are parameter in the index.php

The result should be:

- If I call mydomain.com or mydomain.com/index.php I should see the index.php (normally)
- **If i call mydomain.com/myvar It should redirect to script.php?var=$1**
- But if I call other files (example mydomain.com/page.php) or other directroy (example mydomain.com/folder/)  I should see these files normally, without any redirection.

Is that possible? This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it does redirect everything, including /index.php (without params), /page.php and /folder/

Comment: Is what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is for.. `!-d` means not directroy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite the request path to script.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ script.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also changed your regex pattern to `(.+)` to prevent  the redirection of your homepage `/` .